# How to inject osgi service with felix scr annotations

Tags: osgi

I have a osgi bundle in felix contanier, that exports service

```
@Component(label= "App Service",
    description = "App Service",
    immediate = true, enabled = true, metatype=true)
@Service(AppServiceImpl.class)
public class AppServiceImpl implements AppService {
}
```

in web console I see that service starts normally.

Then I want to inject it with @Reference felix scr annotation in other bundle. I understand that there should be some injector, but could not find it.

Comment: You can normally inject this service in another OSGI service (or Servlet) using @Reference annotation. As far as I know. you don't need injection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Felix SCR bundle? It is the "injector" as it processes the XML generated from these annotations by the tools that assembled your bundles.

Comment: I just can't find this bundle 
http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi
here.

From where can I download this bundle?

Comment: I have 
org.apache.felix.scr-1.8.2.jar this bundle in my felix. did you mean that?

Comment: Yes. I think there is a later version now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven, make sure you have the following instruction in your pom.xml: `<_dsannotations>*</_dsannotations>`
SCR annotations will not work without that.